# Update data from within AsyncTask

Tags: android, list, android-asynctask

How can I add elements to an Array or ArrayList from the AsyncTask class(Inner) , from where I am receiving data from server .

I tried adding elements from doInBackgroud() and printing them in onPostExecute() ,it works fine then .

But the Array and List are both empty when I am trying to access them outside the AsyncTask class.

Code :-

```
public  String[][] mov_details ;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.vpmovies);

    mov_details=new String[NUM_OF_MOVIES][9];
    new MyHttpMovies().execute();
    Toast.makeText(this,mov_details[0][2],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   //prints blank
```

doInBackgroud() and onPostExecute() -

```
 for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                             //parsing some json 


                mov_details[i][0] = (jsonObject.optString("name").toString());
                mov_details[i][1] = (jsonObject.optString("lang").toString());
                mov_details[i][2] = (jsonObject.optString("genre").toString());
                                        . 
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .

return mov_details;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String[][] strings) {
        super.onPostExecute(strings);

         Toast.makeText(VPmovies.this,strings[0][1],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
 // prints successfully

    }
```

Comment: post your code snippet

Comment: First thing you sohuld now : no one can help you, if you didn't post your code

Comment: Will it help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697672/get-result-from-onpostexecute-inner-asynctask-to-oncreate/29697789#29697789

Comment: Make `Array` or `ArrayList` a public static member in the outer class and fill it in inner class of `AsyncTask`

Comment: @JibranKhan i tried that , didn't work

Comment: @user3820753 then please post your code ([not all, just the part we need to solve your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by simply using the `get()` method on the `AsyncTask` instance that would return the output/result of the AsyncTask backgroud thread.

```
mov_details  = new MyHttpMovies().execute().get();   //returns 2d array
```

and instead of using `mov_details` variable inside `doInBackground()` , I used some other 2d array variable local to the just AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    }

public class fetchData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();
          list = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void onPostExecute(Void... params) {
           ...
          list.add("bla bla");
           ...
          return null;
        }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `publishProgress("data")` inside your `doInBackgroung` and pass data from `AsyncTask` to your `Activity/Fragment`. Keep in mind `doInBackgroung` runs in separate thread you can not directly update your main GUI from `doInBackgroung`, if you will call some methods directly from `doInBackgroung` than your calling method should run in main thread.

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    // send data to your required location its recommended to use interfaces for communication
}
```